# Why did Hapoel Be'er Sheva go through over Southampton in UEFA EL 2016-'17?

Tags: football, tie-breaker, europa-league

I scrolled through some soccer leagues and I accidentally came across the following situation. It's about Hapoel Be'er Sheva and Southampton from Group K in the 2016-'17 UEFA Europa League. To start, they both got 8 point in the group stage. So now we're going to apply [the tiebreaker rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016%E2%80%9317_UEFA_Europa_League_group_stage#Tiebreakers):

1. higher number of points obtained in the group matches played among the teams in question;

The two matches between Hapoel Be'er Sheva and Southampton resulted in a 0-0 and 1-1, so in this case they each scored 2 points (because of the two draws).

2. superior goal difference from the group matches played among the teams in question;

The goal difference among Hapoel Be'er Sheva and Southampton is in both matches zero.

3. higher number of goals scored in the group matches played among the teams in question;

In these two matches, Hapoel Be'er Sheva has scored 1 goal and Southampton also has scored 1 goal.

4. higher number of goals scored away from home in the group matches played among the teams in question;

Again, Hapoel Be'er Sheva has scored 1 goal and Southampton also has scored 1 goal.

5. if, after having applied criteria 1 to 4, teams still have an equal ranking, criteria 1 to 4 are reapplied exclusively to the matches between the teams in question to determine their final rankings. If this procedure does not lead to a decision, criteria 6 to 12 apply;
6. superior goal difference in all group matches;

The superior goal difference of Southampton is +2 and that from Hapoel Be'er Sheva is 0.

Then why did Hapoel Be'er Sheva got through over Southampton if Southampton got a higher superior goal difference at rule 6? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the criterion which decides it (emphasis mine).

> 4. higher number of goals **scored away from home** in the group matches played among the teams in question;

It is basically the same as the well-known [away goals rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Away_goals_rule) which is commonly used for two-leg fixtures.

If you look [at the results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016%E2%80%9317_UEFA_Europa_League_group_stage#Group_K) in the matches between these two teams, Hapoel scored one goal in the away match (since the 1-1 draw was in Southampton). Southampton scored no goals away. (In the 0-0 draw was the match played in Beersheba, so Hapeol was the home team and Southampton was the away team.)